# Don't limit rotation in OrbitControls.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using OrbitControls.js to rotate camera around a pivot point. I don't want to limit up/down rotation in any way - I need the camera to "go around" the model ("orbiting" the pivot point).

I tried commenting out the phi limits but then rotating freaks out on top and bottom of the model and acts glitchy for a fraction of a second and then gets back to the limit point anyway.

Any suggestions how to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [TrackballControls](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_trackball) instead of OrbitControls. There is no limitations on rotation in up/down directions.

Comment: Unfortunately the code I'm working on depends on OrbitControls too heavily and I would really like to avoid rewriting the whole thing to use TrackballControls